# How to build a custom table with RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'd like to build a custom table, but I am very new to RMarkdown and I only know how to build a basic table with number of rows and columns.  Could someone please tell me how to do this or point me to some links for custom table.  Thank you.[image]

Comment: @Stedy, I only made a table with 9 x 10 (rows x columns) which was a basic table.   And this table is closer to what I need, but it is in PHP http://fletcher.github.io/MultiMarkdown-5/tables.html

Comment: The `kableExtra` and `huxtable` packages provide relatively intuitive interfaces for building complex tables for rendering in PDF or html. For html tables specifically, there's also the `htmlTable` package. [**Here**](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/design-principles.html) is a comparison of the features of various table-creation packages in R.

Comment: @eipi10, Thank for your info.  I will look for other packages instead of  RMarkdown.

Comment: Not "instead of `Rmarkdown`." You write the document in `Rmarkdown`, but use functions in one of the table-creation packages to generate the table within the `Rmarkdown` document. [**Here**](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-7.html) is the most basic example of this.

Comment: @eipi10,Thank you.